# Dynamically Blocking Websites and Apps in IOS

Tags: ios

We are building an app which will requires to dynamically (in real time) block off users from browsing certain websites or installing/accessing certain apps.

There will be constantly updated list of URL or, Apps that the users simply cannot browse or install from the devices on which this app is installed.

Will greatly appreciate any suggestions on whats possible and how can we go about to implement this?

Comment: Mobile Device Management solution seems to be the only way to do what you want. Look at: http://www.mobileiron.com/en

Answer (score 3):

On the App Store this is not possible.

In the enterprise you can control various aspects of user's iOS device. See for example http://www.csoonline.com/article/2133931/identity-access/mobile-device-management-companies-get-more-app-control-on-ios-7.html

But this is not under the control of an app but IT administration.